# Delete row if the second column value is repeated

Tags: shell, unix

assuming i have the follwing data

```
abcd eeee
efgh eeee
wxyz njtq
abcd rtmk
ijkl mnmn
mnop mnmn
```

and i need to delete entire row if if the second column is repeated

so the output will be in following format

```
abcd eeee
wxyz njtq
abcd rtmk
ijkl mnmn
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '!v[$2] { print; v[$2]=1; } ' input
```

The code checks an associative array, `v`, to see if the second field has been seen before. If this is the first time it sees the field (`v[$2]` is not defined and `!v[$2]` is true), it prints out the line and sets `v[$2]` to 1 so that next time `!v[$2]` evaluates to false.

Gives:

```
abcd eeee
wxyz njtq
abcd rtmk
ijkl mnmn
```